# Align GridView children to top of cell in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using GridView to display a grid of variable-height items, except each cell is aligned to the middle of the row.

[image]

My markup is

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Bounties}" SelectionMode="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" >
  <GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Bounty">
      <Grid>
        <TextBlock Margin="12" MaxWidth="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Text="{x:Bind ItemDefinition.DisplayProperties.Description}"
                   Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

How can I get each cell to align to the top left of its row?

Comment: Hi, do you want to make the height of the `GridViewItem` change with the content (the final effect is like a waterfall flow), or let the `TextBlock` in each `GridViewItem` be topped vertically?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think either will be fine? Basically, I want the cells to all be aligned to the top, not the centre as they are currently.

I reduced the cells to just the text to make the code simpler for the question, but my real cells contain a grid, which i would like to be all aligned with each other https://i.imgur.com/8JjY98L.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal content of the `GridViewItem` is vertically centered, this is the default style, if you want to modify it, please try this:

```xml
<GridView ...>
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

In addition, if you want to make the elements in the GridView adaptive height (the default is the height of the first element or the preset height as the height of all items), you can try [StaggeredPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/staggeredpanel) in Windows Community Toolkit.

Thanks.